# Java Cross-Language Encryption

Tags: java, object, encryption, connection, inputstream

I am working on a game that has multiplayer support and I want to encrypt the server-client connection. I have done it before using a SecretKey object and an ObjectInput/OutputStream. However, I want to leave the ability open for other languages to connect to the server (if I ever take up another language and want to port my game.) Is there any way I could encrypt all the data without using Java objects so any language can use it?

Comment: Could you indicate what is missing from the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Binary object serialization

One action you need to take is to serialize your objects to a binary format. You can do this using the standard serialization API, or you can create your own encoder/decoder. Be sure you describe your own protocol in detail - every bit should be described or you *will* run into trouble - if not directly then several years after.

There are standardized methods or creating your own protocol with binary encodings such as ASN.1, but if you take that route expect a rather steep learning curve. The general idea of using tag/length/value for values is a good one though, so maybe you can take a look at e.g. BER/DER encoding.

### Encryption of your serialized objects

To encrypt, you can create your own cryptographic protocol. Most people on this forum go this route, and most fail. They manage to get their protocol working, but they also leave multiple security holes open.

One of the best ways of securing data in transit is TLS. So if TLS is applicable, by all means go this route. After initial setup, TLS has a relatively low overhead, so there is probably no need to try and implement a competing proprietary protocol.

You can also encrypt at *application level* instead of transport level. A solution to this is to rely on previous standards for *cryptographic constainer formats*. Well known formats are CMS (previously known as PKCS#7) or PGP. PGP and CMS formats are implemented in the Bouncy Castle libraries. They both are binary formats with many options present within them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom object serializer in Java with the [`Externalizable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface. The custom serializer can write out the state of the Java objects so that another language could read them. I've implemented this is a project where I needed serialization to work even if the objects changed and old state needed to be read back. The painful part of custom serialization is that you have to track the object fields carefully or your deserialize methods will create strange bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I did it about six years ago, I serialized the object (so that it was a string) converted the string to a byte array, encrypted the bytes, and sent the data as bytes.  The other end then reversed the process.  I got this to work for encrypted communications between a Java server and an AS3 client.  It won't work for languages that don't support byte arrays though.  Do you need more details?

Comment: I pretty much understand that, but how did you encrypt/decrypt the bytes?

Comment: Every encryption algorithm that I've seen works on blocks of bytes.  If you use a 128 byte encryption algorithm, you take your byte array and process it 128 bytes at a time, etc.